# How to handle variables in nested loops?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops

My script loops through posts on my WordPress site.

I'm also counting the number of unpublished posts and storing it in my `$i` variable.

However, as this is looping through multiple results, I need to store the final `$i` figure in a unique variable after each iteration.

**How should I handle this?** Could I use my `$currentID` variable at any stage?

Here is a snippet of my PHP for reference:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $currentID = get_the_ID();

        while ( $events_list->have_posts() ) :

            $events_list->the_post();

            $postdate = get_the_date('Y-m-d');
            $currentdate = date('Y-m-d');

            if ($postdate > $currentdate) {
                $i++;
            }

        endwhile;

// preferrably store the total of $i here in a unique variable then reset $i

    the_content();

endwhile;
```

Many thanks for any pointers :-)

Comment: Do you mean storing an array of the values of $i after each run through the loop in total?

Comment: Yes. So at the end of each loop, I would have a `$i` total inside a unique variable name.

Comment: If you find yourself thinking something like 'I want to store an arbitrary number of named variables', you actually want one variable with an array of values. Read about arrays and you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have an array holding all of the values by a key of `$currentID`?

```
$postCount = array();
while(condition){
  $currentID = get_the_ID();
  $i = 0; // don't forget to reset your counter
  // processing goes here
  while(condition){
    // more processing goes here
    $i++;
  }
  $postCount[$currentID] = $i;
}
```

That will leave you with an array containing the value of `$i` for each iteration of the outer loop. The values of `$i` will be stored at a key equal to `$currentID`. Don't forget to reset your counter after each iteration!